# How to bind double shift [shift+shift] for quick opening files in SublimeText 3?

Tags: sublimetext3, key-bindings

I am trying to achieve Intellij like double shift navigation.
I found that it is called "Sequence Key Bindings" for "Quick-open files".

Hence, I added this line in `.sublime-keymap --- USER`

```
{ 
  "keys": ["shift", "shift"],  
  "command": "show_overlay", 
  "args": {"overlay": "goto", "text": "@"} 
}
```

But it's not working. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can do this. `shift`, `ctrl`, `alt` and `super` are *modifiers*. You need at least one "normal" key (non-modifier).

As an alternative, here's what you could do:

```
{ "keys": ["g", "g"], "command": "show_overlay", 
  "args": { "overlay": "goto", "text": "@" } }
```

If you never type two `g` at a time, then it's great, otherwise, change it :wink:

(What's going to happen is that the first `g` will be inserted, but if you press a second time the `g`, it will remove both of them and run the command)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

Now in Sublime Text 4, Modifier keys can be uses as part of a key binding. [Sublime Text 4 Changelog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wh8Ae.png)

So now!

```
{ "keys": ["shift", "shift"], "command": "show_overlay", 
  "args": { "overlay": "goto", "text": "@" } }
```